# Delete duplicate entries in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, sql-delete

I have users table which has multiple same user entries and I need to delete duplicate
entries.How to skip foreign key related entries and delete remaining entries. For example below the entries I have in table.I need to delete duplicate entries which is not related to foreign keys.Could any one please guide how to proceed with this in Postgresql?

```
  id     name              email              role_id
 2512 |Raja (Contractor) | raja_test@test.com|5    |
 6    |Raja (Contractor) | raja_test@test.com|5    |
 5    |Raja (Contractor) | raja_test@test.com|5     |
```

I have tried below query

```
delete from users a using users b where a.email=b.email ;
ERROR:  update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_c5e2af0763" on table "devices"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(14) is still referenced from table "devices".
```

Devices table

```
id | mac_address | model | user_id 

14 | 14:5E:BE:26 |Arris |  6
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please label your columns and then tell us what the final output shoud look like.

Comment: Is the value in first column unique?

Comment: I have updated what I have tried.

Comment: you need to show us what the table `devices` looks like, because there is a foreign key in devices that points back to `users`

Comment: I have added devices table.my user_id 6 is linked with this device table.

Comment: What about case where none of the duplicate entries are the parent of a FK, do you want to remove all of them? In others words completely eliminate a user?

Comment: No.I need to remove only duplicates which are not linked with other tables.For example above table I need to remove id 2512 and 5.It should not remove id 6 which is FK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
ALTER TABLE users disable TRIGGER ALL;

-- your delete query  

ALTER TABLE users enable TRIGGER ALL;
```

When we use `disable trigger all` in PostgreSQL, hidden triggers, foreign-key controls, and other constraints for the selected table are also disabled

Comment: I have tried in dev env and used same delete query.It has deleted all data.

Comment: Yes it would as your query will delete anything where a row.email equals itself, so all rows.